# Streaming large files with WSO2 VFS transport

Tags: file, streaming, wso2, esb, vfs

I've got a question regarding the streaming of large files using WSO2 ESB and the VFS transport. I have set up a proxy reading a file from an FTP location. This file should be streamed through WSO2 and be written to a targert location. In order to activate streaming, I have set the transport.vfs.Streaming parameter to "true" on the sender side and I have declared a corresponding property on the receiver side.

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="LargeFileTestProxy" transports="vfs" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable">
<target>
    <inSequence>
        <property xmlns:ns2="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName" expression="fn:concat(fn:substring-after(get-property('MessageID'), 'urn:uuid:'), '.xml')" scope="transport" type="STRING"/>
        <property name="transport.vfs.Streaming" value="true" scope="transport" type="STRING"/>
        <property name="transport.vfs.Append" value="true" scope="transport" type="STRING"/>
        <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        <send>
            <endpoint>
                <address uri="vfs:file:///poc/services/inbound"/>
            </endpoint>
        </send>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence/>
    <faultSequence/>
</target>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.Streaming">true</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.PollInterval">1</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">vfs:ftp://admin:admin@localhost</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*\.xml</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">application/xml</parameter>
```

The transmitted file is partly written to the destination directory and a lock file is generated by WSO2. Unfortunately the rest of the read file isn't appended to the file.

Does anybody know what's wrong with my configuration?

Kind regards,

Heiko

Answer (score 0):

You need to set transport.vfs.Append=true parameter with file address URI, in order to append to the output file [1].

```
<address uri="vfs:file:///poc/services/inbound?transport.vfs.Append=true"/>
```

It doesn't work when you configure it as a VFS property.

[1]http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB450/VFS+Transport

Comment: Thank's for the reply. I have adjusted the address endpoint URI as suggested. Now the file is written to the directory services having the name "inbound?transport.vfs.Append=true". It doesn't seem that the URI is evaluated by WSO2/VFS as expected...

Comment: Hi @Lakmali Erandi Baminiwatta,
how can we upload attachment via wso2 EI API?